# Modifying Components in Java Libraries

Tags: java, log4j2, apache-tika

I was having some problem with `tika-app-2.0.0-ALPHA.jar`. The library itself is using **log4j 1.2**. The version of that log4j is exposed to some vulnerabilities. For my project, I am using **log4j 2.13.3**.

Is there anyway I can disable the **log4j 1.2** used in `tika-app` jar file and point it to the latest log4j which my project is using?

Thanks!

Comment: you can download the source files and change the dependencies on your own... https://tika.apache.org/download.html

Comment: Is there any way I can add some configuration in my project rather than modifying the source code of the library?

Comment: how would you guarantee that `tiki-app-2` is compatible with **log4.2.x**?